# jq select attribute if any array element satisfies a condition

Tags: json, select, jq, any

With the help of **jq** i would like to select all addresses of nodes that have at least one **required=true** in their attribute list. The result list should have unique items.

Here is my Json:

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "address":"127.0.0.1",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id":"abc",
                "required":true
            },
            {
                "id":"def",
                "required":true
            },
            {
                "id":"ghi",
                "required":false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "address":"127.0.0.2",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "id":"abc",
                "required":false
            },
            {
                "id":"def",
                "required":false
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I first tried with:

```
jq '.nodes[] | select(.attributes[].required == true) | .address'
```

This produces:

```
"127.0.0.1"
"127.0.0.1"
```

So it gets the address for every **required=true** field it finds in the attributes section. How to make the result list unique? There is also a unique keyword in jq, but I couldn't figure out how this could help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `unique` is safe but it does require sorting, which may not be necessary.  In your particular case, for example, the repetition is an artifact of the jq query.  Consider using `any` instead (or as well), as it more precisely captures the intention ("at least one"), as well as having "short-circuit" semantics (i.e., it stops searching once the condition is true):

```
$ jq '.nodes[]
| select( any(.attributes[]; .required == true))
| .address' input.json
```

Output:

```
"127.0.0.1"
```

You can always add `unique` if necessary.